# Woocommerce add to cart layout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am new to Woocommerce Integration. The following code displays the cart details:

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id() );
    //product image
    $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );
    echo $getProductDetail->get_image(array( 50, 50 )); // accepts 2 arguments ( size, attr )

    echo "<b>".$_product->get_title() .'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
    $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
    echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
    #Regular Price and Sale Price
    echo "Regular Price: ".get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_regular_price', true)."<br>";
    echo "Sale Price: ".get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_sale_price', true)."<br>";
}
```

But I would like it to display like in cart page with the remove item and quantity field functionalities.

How this can be done?

Comment: Just copy the necessary code from related  [Woocommerce templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) located in Woocommerce plugin under  `templates/cart/` sub-folder starting by `cart.php` file. Your actual code is  outdated with some mistakes. Once done, you will be able to edit your question to ask again (if needed).

Comment: Thankew for your help